# APACHE mod_rewrite change variable name in query string

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get

I'm trying to change a variable name in a query string, so it's usable by my PHP code.

The query gets posts from an external system, so I can't control that they are posting a variable name with a space in it. And that makes it impossible for me to use the PHP `$_GET` function.

I need to change `variable%20name` to `?new1`

And I need to change variable2 to new2

There are many variables passed in the query, but only these two need to be changed. The rest can stay the same or even disappear.

So `?variable%20name=abc&variable2=xyz`

Needs to end up as `?new1=abc&new2=xyz`

Also, they may not be in this order and there may be more variables

So ?variable%20name=abc&blah=123&blah2=456&variable2=xyz

Could end up as `?new1=abc&new2=xyz`

OR as `?new1=abc&blah=123&blah2=456&new2=xyz`

Either way would be fine!

Please give me the **mod_rewrite** rule that will fix this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could just parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: Please tell me more and/or give me an example of the rewrite rule. Or is that a PHP function? I'm lost and need help to complete this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the query string with `mod_rewrite` is a bit of a pain, has to be done with `RewriteCond` and using `%n` replacements in a subsequent `RewriteRule`, probably easier to manually break up the original query string in PHP.

The full query string can be found (within PHP) in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

You can split it up using `preg_split()` or `explode()`, first on `&`, then on `=`, to get key/value pairs.

---

Using `custom%20cbid=123&blahblahblah&name=example` as an example.

```
$params = array();
foreach (explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $cKeyValue) {
    list ($cKey, $cValue) = explode('=', $cKeyValue, 2);
    $params[urldecode($cKey)] = urldecode($cValue);
}

// Would result in:

$params = array('custom cbid' => 123,
                'blahblahblah' => NULL,
                'name' => example);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly give me the exact PHP code to take ?custom%20cbid=123&blahblahblah&name=example and end up with $cbid = 123; $mname = "example" ;

Comment: @Dustin: Example code added, without moving the parameters to separate variables, you can take them out of the resulting array if you wish.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I'm getting closer, but I still don't know how to deal with a variable that has a space in it. How can I make $cbid = 123? (i.e. how do i set the value of $cbid to the value for 'custom cbid'? That's what I really need to know how to do.

Comment: PS I really don't know what I'm doing, so when you say I can take the values out of the resulting array, I go and search Google for "values array php" and try to figure it out. But I haven't had luck yet...

Comment: I also tried this: $cbid = $params['custom cbid']; and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Sweet, I got it to work with: $cbid = $params['custom%20cbid'];

Comment: @Dustin: Sorry, was away. That's a good point, it's encoded, should have put a decode on those fields for you.  Will alter that.